# Header file for STL

Tags: c++, stl

Is it a good and common practice to concentrate for example all STL includes within one header file?

```
// mystlheader.h
//My STL Headerfile 
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <optional>
```

And if I need a std::vector, std::list or any other STL stuff in my project I include only this file (#include "mystlheader.h").

Are there any drawbacks like header file pollution?

Comment: ***Is it a good and common practice to concentrate for example all STL includes within one header file?*** No it is a very bad practice.

Comment: Some compilers already have a similar header file with it, which makes this question very relevant: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: It depends, for example, it could be a good practice if this is a part of precompiled headers.

Comment: The duplicate has no mentioning of precompiled headers, so I am not in agreement with the closure.

Comment: And since some mentione *pre-compiled headers*, even if you have and use those including headers that aren't needed still will have an impact on build time. Much less than without pre-compiled headers, but it's still a little.

Comment: BTW, there is a project here that helps you do the reverse: https://include-what-you-use.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compile time will increase due to so many header files. Use only the files that are needed in a cpp file.